# QGIS Composer - Inserting OS Grid Reference

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I would like to add an OS grid reference to QGIS Composer, i just need to show the figures.  Running on QGIS 2.18.3.

Comment: Ordnance Survey Grid Reference? You just want a point location labelled with coordinates? Or do you want a graticule (grid) in OS coordinates? Do you want the grid square letters, like "SD 0234 1221"?

Comment: Spacedman - I just want to be able to mark a field centre with a grid ref. eg TQ 6734 2175.  then repeat the process on other maps as i have to produce quite a few.

Comment: So the field centre is a point feature layer and you want to label it? You don't want to do it manually (by adding a text object with the grid ref typed in)?

Comment: no, i have multiple maps to create and i'm trying to make a template that will (among other things) give a 6 figure grid reference for the field centre that is being surveyed.  I suppose it needs to track the centre point of the composer map with reference to the map layer in GIS.  Ross